# gcc, inline assembly - pushad/popad missing?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, stack, inline-assembly

Any way to avoid having to copy-paste the `pushad`/`popad` instruction body into my code?

Because gcc (current flags: `-Wall -m32`) complains that

```
__asm__("pushad;");
```

> Error: no such instruction: `pushad'

```
__asm__("popad;");
```

> Error: no such instruction: `popad'

Comment: Just FYI, it's almost always better to let the compiler save/restore registers if it wants to.  Use constraints to tell it which regs you want to clobber, or better: to let it pick temp regs for you.  See the inline asm links in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GCC use AT/T assembly syntax, while `pushad/popad` are Intel convention, try this:

```
__asm__("pushal;");
__asm__("popal;");
```